# Cannot download Windows installer

Tags: miktex, texlive, windows

I'm just trying to get started with LaTeX on Windows 64 bit, but have quickly hit an unexpected roadblock. I first tried TeX Live, but the download is very slow and would always fail before completing. I tried several mirrors, but the result was the same. I tried several different browsers, but the result was the same. I tried continuing the download when it stopped, over and over again until it finally completed, but the binary was corrupt.

I decided to switch to MiKTeX, but have been having exactly the same issues there. However, it seems like both options may be hosted on the same infrastructure...?

Can anyone confirm whether the Windows installers are downloading for them? For example, [this one](https://miktex.org/download/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/setup/basic-miktex-2.9.6520-x64.exe). If not, any advice on how to proceed?

EDIT: after 4 attempts, I finally got the net installer to download. But of course, it just tries to download the full package from the same source, so it also eventually fails:

[image]

Comment: Just downloaded it using your link. Took me less than 3 minutes. Try downloading from a faster internet connection.

Comment: I've actually tried two networks - one is 4G and the other is a fast (by Australian standards) network at work. Not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: @me-- try Protext https://www.ctan.org/pkg/protext

Comment: @AndréC I doubt that this would help, the problem seems to be a sketchy internet connection and protext is large too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The main difference is that there is only one `.exe` extension file to download and the browser as chrome (for example) in this case automatically resumes the download when it has been interrupted. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?hl=en

Comment: @AndréC The basic installer of miktex is one exe too, and if it took four attempts to download sucessfully, it won't be easy with the larger protext exe.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer MikTeX consists of an `.exe` file that downloads one by one the files into a folder named `MiKTeX Download Files`, the browser does not support downloading. But with protext, the browser manages the download itself and resumes it until it is complete.

Comment: @AndréC The OP wrote that he/she has problems with the download  of`basic-miktex-2.9.6520-x64.exe` (see the link in the question) which is one large 200MB-exe. He/she seems also to had problems to download the netinstaller which is much smaller. Why do you think that he/she will be able to download a 2000MB-file without problems?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because the browser automatically takes care of the cuts and automatically resumes downloading a single file as soon as it can, even if the file is very large.

Comment: @AndréC It may work for you but looking at the question why do you believe it will also work for the OP as in his/her case the browser didn't take care of the cuts for the much smaller basic-miktex.exe? You don't know the browser the OP is using and don't have an idea why the downloads failed. So why do you advise someone with a 4G-internet to try a 2000MB download?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It should try to download the basic version with Chrome.

Comment: Are you behind a university network firewall? Does it block FTP file transfers? If so, is the installer trying to connect to FTP sources?

Comment: In the past 2 things have helped me when I have had this problem.  1- using the wget program at the command prompt (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) 2- Using Firefox with the "DownThemAll" extension which allows parallel download streams (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)